# Indent after opening php tag

Tags: php, phpstorm

I just started using PhpStorm, and it doesn't want me to indent the first line after the opening `<?php` tag. I prefer to, so I do it manually each time. This may seem rather trivial, but after searching I cannot find any definitive reasons to do it one way or the other. Is there a best practice for indenting after opening a script tag?

Comment: It is telling you to stop making up strange coding style ;-) I.e. don't indent after opening PHP tag.

Comment: Personally, I indent after opening PHP tag too. I found a way to edit it in the preferences before.

Comment: Best practice is to indent when you go down a level in scope, i.e. opening a class or function. Whether you choose to view opening a php tag as going down a level in scope is up to you. I don't do it.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to indent it. It is for a visual queue when you logic is nested in some way.

Comment: In a file falling in and out of HTML, it makes sense to indent the PHP as a visual cue.

Comment: @NicholasPickering Hence why you don't mix PHP and HTML in the same file, unless it's a template file - in which case there should be no "blocks" of PHP. Separate view from logic, _please_.

Comment: Are you talking about **Settings | Code Style | PHP | Other | Indent code in PHP tags** ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While not directly defined, [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md), [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), and [PSR-3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md) do not indent after the PHP tags. Since the PSR's are the defacto standard of PHP coding styles I would recommend sticking to the PSR Standards and trying to break your habit of the initial indent, if for no other reason to reduce the length of lines and thus line wraps and line breaks.

Answer (score 9):

Open PhpStorm's settings. Under *Project Settings -> Code Style -> PHP* you should find a tab *Other* where you can set the desired behavior by clicking the checkbox *Indent code in PHP tags*.

But as the other answer suggests, this is probably not a good idea, as it is against any common coding standard I know of. :-)

Comment: I agree. I'll adjust my practices. Jeremey1026's answer was what I was looking for to motivate my switch.

Comment: I personally dislike the PSR coding style, so it doesn't really matter to me. Thank you for posting the actual answer to this question, because indenting within the php tags make the code a ton more readable.

Comment: awesome. very much appreciated